# find duplicate values within delimiter

Tags: sql, oracle

Great, that was my first question posted and i got reply so fast. :-)

Let me be more clear with my query. Here is table structure :-

```
CREATE TABLE ct_collreview_atg (csku NUMBER, merch_opt NUMBER, ri_seq VARCHAR2(4000));

Insert into CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG Values (100293, 17, ',5,');
Insert into CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG Values (100293, 17, ',10,');
Insert into CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG Values (100293, 17, ',70,');
Insert into CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG Values (100293, 17, ',30,60,');
Insert into CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG Values (100293, 17, ',30,80,');
Insert into CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG Values (100293, 17, ',30,50,');
Insert into CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG Values (100293, 17, ',20,50,');
Insert into CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG Values (100293, 17, ',40,');
Insert into CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG Values (100293, 17, ',110,');
Insert into CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG Values (100293, 17, ',90,');
Insert into CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG Values (100293, 17, ',100,');
COMMIT;
```

Now if i do a 'Select * from ct_collreview_atg;'

i get this data set :-

```
CSKU  |MERCH_OPT  |RI_SEQ

100293  |17 |,5,
100293  |17 |,10,
100293  |17 |,70,
100293  |17 |,30,60,
100293  |17 |,30,80,
100293  |17 |,30,50,
100293  |17 |,20,50,
100293  |17 |,40,
100293  |17 |,110,
100293  |17 |,90,
100293  |17 |,100,
```

If you see clearly, 30 & 50 are being repeated in multiple rows. so what i want is a query which will just display me the numbers which are being repeated. In this case it should display 30 & 50 as rest all numbers are occuring once.

my version of oracle is (10.2.0.3.0)
Thanks for you help.

Comment: I have to ask... Sorry. Why isn't this properly normalised so that you could do it with a group by? Is there any way you could normalise it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused -- I don't see a duplicate in the example.

In any case, some Googling suggests that using GROUP BY and HAVING might be your ticket:

```
select csku, merch_opt, ri_seq from ct_collreview_atg
where rec_type = 'PROD'
and row_status = 'A'
and csku = 100293
GROUP BY csku, merch_opt
HAVING ( count(cksu) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an auxiliary table say TSEQ with the values that occur in the column RI_SEQ  (or you can generate this table  if the values are sequential ).

For instance,

```
Create table TSEQ (SEQ varchar(3));
insert into tseq values ("5");
insert into tseq values ("50"),
...
insert into tseq values ("110"),
etc.
```

Then you join TSEQ and CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG on RI_SEQ containing SEQ and get the groups of lines that repeat SEQ  using group by having count(*)  like this:

```
select seq,count(*) from tseq join CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG t on ri_seq  like '%,'||seq||',%' group by 1 having count(*) >1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, **[Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm)** may work:

```
   with dups as(
select 
          t.ri_seq
         , regexp_substr (t.ri_seq, '[^,]+', 1, rn) spl
    from CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG t
     cross
     join (select rownum rn
       from (select max (length (regexp_replace (t.ri_seq, '[^,]+'))) + 1 mx
                     from CT_COLLREVIEW_ATG t
                  )
          connect by level <= mx
          )
   where regexp_substr (t.ri_seq, '[^,]+', 1, rn) is not null)
select distinct spl from (
select spl, row_number() over (partition by spl order by 1) dp from dups)
where dp>1
```

The query above first splits comma separated values into rows, and then it detects duplicates within these rows. In this example, 30&50.

**[Here](http://nuijten.blogspot.com/2011/08/splitting-comma-delimited-string-regexp.html)** is the original query.